# Laravel 7 Job queue handle method is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-queue

I am trying to execute a code after some delay using laravel 7 job queue. The constructor method is working but not the handle method. My code is given below:

**Controller:**

```
public function test()
{
    echo 'starting ....';
    $reset = (new ResetLockers())->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
    dispatch($reset);
}
```

**Job:**

```
class ResetLockers implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'constructing ...';
    }

    
    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'job dispatched';
    }
}
```

**database:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

any clue?

Comment: any clue about what?

Comment: why the handle method is not working??

Comment: why are you assuming it isn't working?

Comment: echo 'job dispatched'; this piece of code is not working which is inside handle method. @lagbox

Comment: and where would you be expecting to see that echo? considering the queue worker is a completely separate process from the one handling the web request

Comment: yes. actually it was working in my console. I didn't notice. solved ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have configured your queue, but the `handle()` method is only called when the job is being processed by your queue. Your code is is just delaying the dispatch by 10 seconds.

Comment: in my .env file i use QUEUE_CONNECTION=database and i run php artisan queue:listen database . but no luck.

Comment: try writing some different logic in handle() to confirm if it's working or not. Maybe an INSERT statement?

Comment: try this 
php artisan queue:work

Answer (score 0):

try updating the

> php artisan queue:restart

method and try again if the code is up to date